# g++: array bound is not an integer constant

Tags: c++, g++, constants

With the code,

```
const double rotationStep = 0.001;
const int N = 2*int(M_PI/rotationStep) + 3;

static unsigned int counts[N];
```

`g++` gives the error:

> array bound is not an integer constant before »]« token

I am using `g++`/`gcc` version 4.6.1

Can anybody tell me why `g++` complains about the expression?

Comment: Please, can you delete the `static` token out of your code and recompile?

Comment: @h3nr1x: It's implementation defined behavior (when the expression is evaluated that is).

Comment: won't compile without static keyword either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the ISO C++ standard of 2003, that's not an *integral constant-expression*. Quoting section 5.19 of the standard:

> An *integral constant-expression* can involve only literals (2.13),
>   enumerators, `const` variables or static data members of integral or
>   enumeration types initialized with constant expressions (8.5),
>   non-type tem-plate parameters of integral or enumeration types, and
>   `sizeof` expressions.  Floating literals (2.13.3) can appear only if
>   they are cast to integral or enumeration types.

You could change this:

```
const double rotationStep = 0.001;
const int N = 2*int(M_PI/rotationStep) + 3;
```

to this:

```
const int inverseRotationStep = 1000;
const int N = 2*int(M_PI)*inverseRotationStep + 3;
```

(That's assuming `M_PI` is defined somewhere; it's not specified in the standard, but it's a common extension.)

The 2011 ISO C++ standard loosens this up a bit. 5.19p3 (quoting the N3337 draft) says:

> An *integral constant expression* is a literal constant expression of
>   integral or unscoped enumeration type.

I *think* `2*int(M_PI/rotationStep) + 3`, and therefore `N`, qualifies under the new rules, but it's likely your compiler doesn't yet implement them.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that...

```
g++ gives: array bound is not an integer constant before »]« token
```

A `const` value is not a constant expression (though its quite understandable why this would confuse you).

EDIT: I assumed C when I first read this.  The problem here is that this expression is not being evaluated at compile time:

```
const int N = 2*int(M_PI/rotationStep) + 3;
```

While this would be

```
const int N = 10;
```

As @ildjarn noted in the comments, floating point arithmetic is not guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time.  [Here is a related SO post I found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417155/floating-point-arithmetic-at-compile-time)

Comment: -_- but N is fixed at compile time :/
So is there a another solution to using #define ?

Comment: @user765269 : Floating-point arithmetic is not guaranteed to be performed at compile time like integral arithmetic is.

Comment: @user765269: I was actually thinking C when I read this (which has a more restrictive definition of what constitutes a constant expression), not C++.  The problem is that the expression is *not* evaluated at compile time.

Comment: If you take out the `static` keyword it should compile without warnings

Comment: @h3nr1x: it's implementation defined.  For example, VS2010 still throws a hissy fit.

Comment: @h3nr1x: How so? C++ (unlike C starting with C99) doesn't have variable-length arrays -- though some compilers may support them as an extension.

Comment: @EdS. Do you mean that the `const` declaration with floating point is the implementation defined part or the use of the `static` keyword in the declaration?

Comment: @h3nr1x: The floating point part, i.e., when the expression will be evaluated.

Comment: @KeithThompson I just copy/pasted the code, compiled it using `g++ test.cpp`, and then it throwed the same error message, after that, I deleted the `static` keyword, and the error message disappeared

Comment: @h3nr1x: Try compiling with `g++ -pedantic`. I get "warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘counts’ [-Wvla]". (g++ is non-conforming by default.)

Answer (score 1):

As Ed already pointed out, optimizations of floating point operations, including constant folding, are not guaranteed to happen at compile time. [Intel's page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/proguide/ref/cvfltar.htm) on the subject gives a few examples, but mainly it's that the rounding behavior may be different and that floating point operations may throw exceptions. [This paper](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) goes a bit more in-depth (section 8.3, "Arithmetic Reduction").

GCC does only support

> "floating-point expression contraction such as forming of fused multiply-add operations if the target has native support for them"

as mentioned in the description for the ffp-contract flag in the [compiler optimizations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) manual.

Comment: *"**compile-time** floating point operations are not guaranteed to **happen at compile time**."* - Can't get much more confusing than that! :D