# c++11: Array bound is not an integer constant before a token

Tags: c++11, vector

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269623/g-array-bound-is-not-an-integer-constant), but the solution provided there doesn't solve the issue.

```
static int num_instances; 
std::vector<SomeClass::FunctionWithinTheClass> *mem[num_instances];
```

`SomeClass::FunctionWithinTheClass *mem[num_instances];` //Even this raises an error

the value `num_instances` is obtained by reading a configuration file.

The error I get is :
`array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token`

This is strange because the value `num_instances` is fixed at compile time.

Comment: You're reading a config file at compile time?

Comment: No, the config file is read at runtime.

Comment: Then the value is determined at runtime, isn't it?

Comment: That's correct. Then, I need to understand what the issue is

Comment: The issue is that the value must be a compile-time constant. Hence know at compile time.

Comment: How does one make that constant?

Comment: What situation requires an array of pointers to vectors, for $DEITY's sake?

Comment: If you don't _know_ the correct value of `num_instances` at compile time, you can't make it a compile-time constant. Only compile-time constants are legal array sizes (C VLAs and compiler extensions aside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the value `num_instances` is obtained by reading a configuration file

and

> ... the config file is read at runtime

That means `num_instances` is a *variable* whose value is determined at *run time*.

> This is strange because the value `num_instances` is fixed at compile time

No it isn't, you're contradicting yourself.

If it's loaded from config at run time, it wasn't known at compile time. If it was known at compile time, you wouldn't be loading it from config at run time.

---

If you cannot fix `num_instances` at compile time, an array is the wrong thing to use. Just change it to

```
// like an array whose size can be set at runtime ...
std::vector<std::vector<SomeClass::FunctionWithinTheClass>> mem;

void configure() {
    size_t num_instances = loadNumInstancesFromConfig();
    mem.resize(num_instances);
}
```

Comment: Why is it `std::vector<std::vector` ?

Comment: What did I say it was trying to achieve? What would make sense? How does it read when you match the `<...>` brackets around the template parameter lists?

Comment: I reread that and understood it better, which leads me to a new error: `request for member resize in ..., which is of pointer type (maybe you meant to use ->`

Comment: Did you declare `mem` as a pointer still? It doesn't need to be, which is why I didn't declare it as one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is fixed at compile time but “integer constant” is a technical term and a `static int` variable does not meet these requirements.

Use a `static const int` instead. This works:

```
static const int num_instances = 5;
```

However, you mention that `num_instances` is read from a configuration file… this does not sound remotely like a constant to me. In this case, you must use a `std::vector` or other dynamically sized array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the value is fixed, it's not a compile time constant, if you want dynamically sized container might I suggest you use stl containers?