# array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token when it is actually constant

Tags: c

I am trying to have an array, which has a defined size known during compile time.

```
const uint8_t a[2] = {0, 127}; // Fine
const uint8_t aRange = a[1] - a[0]; // Fine
double sums[aRange]; //Fails
```

But this fails by gcc with

> error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token.

As a workaround I intend to use macro variables. But would like to know if there is any logic behind it. There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269623/g-array-bound-is-not-an-integer-constant) answer, which is most related. However, according to the answer, it should have worked.

Comment: In the global (non-function) scope, all array sizes *must* be compile-time constants. And even if you define `aRange` as `const` it's not a compile-time constant. The `const` qualifier in C only says that the variables value can't be modified.

Comment: Upgrade to C++ https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G6Bh2q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aRange` is a constant integer, but not an integer constant.  Isn't English a fun language?

- C11 [§6.4.4.1 Integer constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1)
- C11 [§6.6 Constant expressions ¶6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p6)

  - *An integer constant expression<sup>117)</sup> shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.*
  - *<sup>117)</sup> An integer constant expression is required in a number of contexts such as the size of a bit-field member of a structure, the value of an enumeration constant, and the size of a non-variable length array. Further constraints that apply to the integer constant expressions used in conditional-inclusion preprocessing directives are discussed in 6.10.1.*
- C11 [§6.7.6.2 Array declarators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2) — one of the more inscrutable parts of the standard.  (¶2 is a constraint; ¶4 and ¶5 specify the semantics of array declarators.)

  - *¶2 If an identifier is declared as having a variably modified type, it shall be an ordinary identifier (as defined in 6.2.3), have no linkage, and have either block scope or function prototype scope. If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.*
  - *¶4 If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is `*` instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size, which can only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope;<sup>143)</sup> such arrays are nonetheless complete types. If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type. (Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see 6.10.8.3.)*
  - *<sup>143)</sup> Thus, `*` can be used only in function declarations that are not definitions (see 6.7.6.3).*
  - *¶5 If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: if it occurs in a declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by `*`; otherwise, each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero. The size of each instance of a variable length array type does not change during its lifetime. Where a size expression is part of the operand of a `sizeof` operator and changing the value of the size expression would not affect the result of the operator, it is unspecified whether or not the size expression is evaluated.*

At file (global) scope, you must have an integer constant expression for the dimensions of an array.  In a local variable in C99 or later, what you've written would be OK for a VLA (variable-length array).

You could work around this with:

```
enum { A_MIN = 0, A_MAX = 127 };
const uint8_t a[2] = { A_MIN, A_MAX };
const uint8_t aRange = a[1] - a[0];
double sums[A_MAX - A_MIN];
```

In C, you can't write `const uint8_t aRange = a[1] - a[0];` at file (global) scope, so your code should have been OK unless you're using an antiquated C compiler that doesn't recognize C99 or later (or it defines `__STDC_NO_VLA__`).

Comment: I was thinking that compiler is smart enough to make constant integers, integer constants, since everything necessary is actually known during compile time.

Comment: The C language doesn't allow that.  C++ has different rules; you'd probably be OK there.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan's answer is accepted. As a workaround I used macros though.

```
#define A_MIN 0
#define A_MAX 127
const uint8_t a[2] = {A_MIN, A_MAX};
const uint8_t aRange = A_MAX - A_MIN;
double sums[aRange];
```

Comment: See: [`static const` vs `#define` vs `enum`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1674032/15168)