# Can’t define a global array in C with its size defined as a symbolic constant

Tags: c, gcc

The size of the array is defined as a symbolic constant(macro) as given below:

`#define N (int)(N_AB+0.5*(LxIni+LxIni))`

N is used later to declare global arrays consisting of double elements.
The global arrays are declared as follows:

`double rx[N];`

However, I get the following error:

`variably modified ‘rx’ at file scope`

could you please help me with this?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please post what is `N_AB` and `LxIni`. What is the point of `0.5*(LxIni+LxIni)`? `N is used later to declare global array’s consisting of double elements` Please instead of explaining , _show_ the code. How is `N` used _exactly in code_? `int rx[N][N]`?

Comment: Likely duplicate (among many...): [**array bound is not an integer constant before '\]' token when it is actually constant**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694542/array-bound-is-not-an-integer-constant-before-token-when-it-is-actually-cons)

Comment: N_AB and LxIni are also symbolic constants to compute N.

Comment: `N_AB and LxIni are also symbolic constants to compute N` What is a "symbolic constant"? Please do not explain the code, please _show_ the code instead. Please `Edit` your post and post additional helpful information there. In C language there is no "symbolic constant"s - an identifier introduced with `#define` is called a "macro".

Comment: @Falcons Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include some minimal code

Comment: Why do you calculate half the sum of  `LxIni` and `LxIni`?  It is “harmless” but hardly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> variably modified ‘rx’ at file scope

This error message means that you may not define a variable length array with static storage duration (file scope variables have static storage duration). You need to allocate the array dynamically or declare it in a block scope. In the last case without the storage specifier static it will have automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

The floating-point `0.5` prevents the array size from being considered an integer constant expression. You can divide by the integer `2` instead, changing `0.5*(LxIni+LxIni)` to `(LxIni+LxIni)/2`. You could also change it to `LxIni`, which should be mathematically equivalent if there is no overflow or wrapping. (Is that a typo, did you mean to add two different things rather than adding something to itself and then dividing by two, which seems pointless?)

This is intentional in the design of C; the size of a static-duration array must be an integer constant expression, which cannot use floating-point operands in arithmetic (except that a C implementation could choose to allow them).

C 2018 6.7.6.2 2 says objects with static storage duration (which includes arrays defined outside functions) must not have a variable length array type:

> … If an identifier is declared to be an object with static or thread storage duration, it shall not have a variable length array type.

6.7.6.2 4 says if the size is not an integer constant expression, the array is a variable length array type:

> … If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a *variable length array type*; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type…

6.6 6 restricts the use of floating-point constants in integer constant expressions [bold added]:

> … An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and **floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts**…

A C implementation could choose to support floating-point arithmetic in integer constant expressions, as 6.6 10 says:

> An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.

However, your implementation apparently choose not to do so.